# How to move picbutton? Pyqt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a button from a picture.
I found this code in here, but i cant move the picture, how can i do that?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class PicButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
      #  painter.drawPixmap(100,1, self.pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(500,1,100,100, self.pixmap,0,0,100,100)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.pixmap.size()


def close():
    print("xxx")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QHBoxLayout(window)
window.setFixedSize(740, 850) #window size.

button = PicButton(QPixmap("thinking.png"))
button.clicked.connect(close)
layout.addWidget(button)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can move in x axis but cant in y axis.
How can i do that?
And is there any cursor style to make this more like button?
Thank you.

here is output

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to move the button? I do not see any code that does it.

Comment: @eyllanesc, i tried button.move but it didnt worked.    painter.drawPixmap(500,1,100,100, self.pixmap,0,0,100,100) 500 is x axis, but i cant find how to move in y axis

Comment: you say *I can move in x*, how do you do that?

Comment: try with: `painter.drawPixmap(100, 100,100,100, self.pixmap,0,0,100,100) `

Comment: How big is the image ?, just in case with that code you are not moving anything, you are only drawing in the QWidget and you are probably out of the widget space and that is why you assume that it does not move.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks i tried but result is empty.

Comment: @eyllanesc its 64*64, yes i understand this right now, but how can i avoid this widget problem? Is there any way to do this button pic?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I do not understand you.

Comment: @eyllanesc i want to convert the picture to a button. so i can add a clicked function to this picture. but i can not find any way to do it. this code not working because i cant move the picture in the window.

Comment: Use `painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(), self.pixmap)`

Comment: Why do you want to move the image?

Comment: @eyllanesc i have another program, there are buttons, i want to turn them into a pic. so i need a movement. that code so long so i couldnt add here.

Comment: @eyllanesc shouldnt i use widget? how can i change this code?

Comment: try with this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/8ec9ec1468ae13ce2b7bf842bb299f35

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you it worked so good. finally can i ask how can i use button.setStyleSheet ? button.setStyleSheet("QAbstractButton:hover{ "
                        "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);"
                        "color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);") not worked.

Comment: you can not combine or use QSS or use QPainter. please, if you are in the process of learning, try the basic examples, understand them, modify them. You are trying to run and you do not know how to crawl.